# Why we use dequeueReusable key word in ios

Tags: ios, iphone, objective-c, uitableview, mkmapview

I am wondering Why we using dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier or dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier ? For example defaultPinID value is not logical. if I change value of defaultPinID , nothing change.At that case Why we using dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier(Key word dequeueReusable)  ?

in MkMapView

```
 - (MKAnnotationView *)mapView:(MKMapView *)mapView viewForAnnotation:(id <MKAnnotation>)annotation
    {
         MKAnnotationView *pinView = nil;
         static NSString *defaultPinID = @"ftffggf"; 
         pinView = (MKAnnotationView *)[self.mapView dequeueReusableAnnotationViewWithIdentifier:defaultPinID];  // why ? 
         .........
         ...........

         return pinView;

    }
```

in tableView

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

        static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

        UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];// why ? 

        if (cell == nil)
        {
            cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier];

        }
        ................
        ............... 
        return cell;

    }
```

Comment: Because we want to use the same cell which is displayed earlier & not created new cell.

Answer (score 3):

It's a resource thing, nothing may change from looking at the application.  But if the cell is able to be recycled if it has been initialized before it saves you some overhead of having to allocate it over and over again as the user scrolls up and down.

Comment: In addition: defaultPinID is used to identify what type of recycled cell tableview/mapview should use. You can have multiple types of cell in one tableview and use multiple reusable keys.

Answer (score 2):

The construction and initialization of a UIView-derived resource is relatively expensive. Since TableViews, MapViews, and CollectionViews usually need to show only a small number on screen at a time, but need to scroll through a potentially large number of objects (as the user pans around on the map or scrolls through collection/table views) Apple optimized those classes to reuse already created instances of their data items. This is what makes a table view of thousands of rows scroll fast and fluid - it doesn't have to create a whole new view object every time a row scrolls into view, then destroy it as it scrolls out of view. I just reuses an already created instance and changes the data displayed on it.